# Kendo UI Grid Paging messages - show message on exceeding row limit

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Pageable feature to show the custom message like:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
// skipped other codes 
scrollable: true,
sortable: true,
pageable: { 
pageSize: 20, 
pageSizes: true, 
buttonCount: 5,
messages: { display: "(Search limit reached : 50,000 ) {0} - {1} of {2} items" }
}
```

But, I want to include the mentioned extra text "(Search limit reached : 50,000 )" only when the grid total row count crosses 50,000.

How, to achieve this ? 
Can you use some template with conditions? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a global variable `msg` in `messages: { display: msg+" {0} - {1} of {2} items" }` and initialize `msg` in the `fetch()` at the time of data binding.

```
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var pageSize = parseInt(grid.dataSource.pageSize());
  if(parseInt(index)*pageSize > 9)
    {msg ="(Search limit reached : 9 )";}
    else
    {msg = "";}
  return msg;
```

you can see working example at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ns6J9ZrvdlvWSf8f1VUT?p=preview):

**JS**

```
 // Code goes here
    var dataS = [
      {ContactName : 'vishal', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal1', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal2', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal3', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal4', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal5', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal6', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal7', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal8', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'},
    {ContactName : 'vishal9', ContactTitle: 'Mr', Country:'India'}];

    var msg = "";

    function fetch(index)
    { 

      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      var pageSize = parseInt(grid.dataSource.pageSize());
      if(parseInt(index)*pageSize > 9)
        {msg ="(Search limit reached : 9 )";}
        else
        {msg = "";}
      return msg;
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: dataS,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        ContactName: { type: "string" },
                        ContactTitle: { type: "string" },
                        Country: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 4
        },


        columns: [{
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 80
        }, {
            field: "ContactTitle",
            title: "Contact Title",
            width: 80
        }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: 150
        }],

        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            change: function (e) {
                var $this = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var msg = fetch(e.index);
                $this.pager.options.messages.display = msg + " {0} - {1} of {2} items";
                $this.dataSource.read();
                $this.refresh();
            }
        },


    });
});
```